# Multiple linear regression in GSL is correct?

Tags: r, linear-regression, gsl

I was attempting to perform multiple linear regression using GSL. The estimator for beta is beta=(X'X)^(-1)X'y. Three approaches were used -

1. direct, i.e. calculate the right-hand side of this formula using required operations;
2. solve the X'Xb=X'y, i.e. solve the system Ax=b, where A=X'X, b=X'y, and x=b;
3. use function gsl_multifit_linear. The test data are from [here](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Reg2.html).

All three approaches gave same wrong result:

beta1=0.0365505, beta2=0.0435827, alpha=0.645627.

The same data file produces correct output in R:

beta1=0.086409, beta2=0.087602, alpha=-4.1.

Results for another dataset (WHO life expectancy data from [here](https://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.main.688?lang=en)) also differed between GSL and R.

Most likely I have a mistake somewhere. But it would be good if at least somebody can confirm that GSL multiple linear regression works correctly.

Edit1.
The language is C++.
The code for option1, i.e. beta=(X'X)^(-1)X'y

```cpp
void mols(vector <double> predictandVector,vector <vector <double> > predictorMatrix) {
        //the function accepts vector of predictant values and matrix of predictands
        //convert input vectors into gsl_vector
        int n=predictandVector.size();
        int m=predictorMatrix[0].size();
        gsl_vector*y=gsl_vector_alloc(n);
        gsl_matrix*x=gsl_matrix_alloc(n,m);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                gsl_vector_set(y,i,predictandVector[i]);
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        gsl_matrix_set(x,i,j,predictorMatrix[i][j]);
                }
        }
        //multiply X' by X
        gsl_matrix*xxTranspose=gsl_matrix_alloc(m,m);
        gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasTrans,CblasNoTrans,1.0,x,x,0.0,xxTranspose);
        /////////////////////////////////
        //perform LU decomposition of xxTranspose to find it's inverse
        gsl_permutation*p=gsl_permutation_alloc(m);
        int s;
        gsl_linalg_LU_decomp(xxTranspose,p,&s);
        //////////////////////////////
        //compute inverse of xxTranspose matrix
        gsl_matrix*xxTransposeInverse=gsl_matrix_alloc(m,m);
        gsl_linalg_LU_invert(xxTranspose,p,xxTransposeInverse);
        //////////////////////////////
        //multiply inverse of xxTranspose matrix by xTranspose
        gsl_matrix*xxTransposeInverseXtranspose=gsl_matrix_alloc(m,n);
         gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasNoTrans,CblasTrans,1.0,xxTransposeInverse,x,0.0,xxTransposeInverseXtranspose);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        //multiply matrix (X'X)^(-1)X' and vector y; this must give values of beta
        gsl_vector*b=gsl_vector_alloc(m);
        gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasNoTrans,1.0,xxTransposeInverseXtranspose,y,0.0,b);
        //write beta values to file
        FILE*f;
        f=fopen("molsResult.dat","w");
        gsl_vector_fprintf(f,b,"%g");
        ////////////////////
}
```

The code for option2, i.e. solve the system X'Xbeta=X'y

```cpp
oid mols(vector <double> predictandVector,vector <vector <double> > predictorMatrix) {
        //convert input vectors into gsl_vector
        int n=predictandVector.size();
        int m=predictorMatrix[0].size();
        gsl_vector*y=gsl_vector_alloc(n);
        gsl_matrix*x=gsl_matrix_alloc(n,m);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                gsl_vector_set(y,i,predictandVector[i]);
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        gsl_matrix_set(x,i,j,predictorMatrix[i][j]);
                }
        }
        /////////////////////
        //compute X'X
        gsl_matrix*xxTranspose=gsl_matrix_alloc(m,m);
        gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasTrans,CblasNoTrans,1.0,x,x,0.0,xxTranspose);
        /////////////////////////////////
        //compute X'y
        gsl_vector*XtransposeY=gsl_vector_alloc(m);
        gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasTrans,1.0,x,y,0.0,XtransposeY);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        //solve the linear system X'Xb=X'y to find coefficients beta
        gsl_vector*b=gsl_vector_alloc(m);
        int k=n;
        if(m<n) {
                k=m;
        }
        gsl_vector*tau=gsl_vector_alloc(k);
        gsl_linalg_QR_decomp(xxTranspose,tau);
        gsl_linalg_QR_solve(xxTranspose,tau,XtransposeY,b);
        //write beta values into file
        FILE*f;
        f=fopen("molsResult.dat","w");
        gsl_vector_fprintf(f,b,"%g");
        ////////////////////////////////
}
```

The code for option3, i.e. using gsl_multifit_linear.

```cpp
void mols(vector <double> predictandVector,vector <vector <double> > predictorMatrix) {
        //convert input vectors into gsl_vector
        int n=predictandVector.size();
        int m=predictorMatrix[0].size();
        gsl_vector*y=gsl_vector_alloc(n);
        gsl_matrix*x=gsl_matrix_alloc(n,m);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                gsl_vector_set(y,i,predictandVector[i]);
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        gsl_matrix_set(x,i,j,predictorMatrix[i][j]);
                }
        }
        ///////////////////////////
        //Use gsl_multifit_linear
        gsl_multifit_linear_workspace*w=gsl_multifit_linear_alloc(n,2);
        double chisq;
        gsl_matrix*cov=gsl_matrix_alloc(m,m);
        gsl_vector*b=gsl_vector_alloc(m);
        gsl_multifit_linear(x,y,b,cov,&chisq,w);
        //////////////////////
        //write beta values into file
        FILE*f;
        f=fopen("molsResult.dat","w");
        gsl_vector_fprintf(f,b,"%g");
        //////////////////////////
}
```

Edit2.
Also to absolutely assure that input data is read in correctly the following code as added to the option3 code:

```cpp
FILE*xyWrite;
        xyWrite=fopen("molsInputData.dat","w");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                fputs(to_string(gsl_vector_get(y,i)).c_str(),xyWrite);
                fputs(" ",xyWrite);
                fputs(to_string(gsl_matrix_get(x,i,0)).c_str(),xyWrite);
                fputs(" ",xyWrite);
                fputs(to_string(gsl_matrix_get(x,i,1)).c_str(),xyWrite);
                fputs("\n",xyWrite);
        }
```

This code writes gsl_vector(s) x and y (used as input) into file. Then this file was loaded into R and multiple linear regression performed. The results were correct. This proves that input data is read in correctly.

Comment: **Please post the code you have tried in the question.** And when you say GSL, are you running C code, C++ code or is it the R package `gsl`?

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522882/how-can-i-use-gsl-to-calculate-polynomial-regression-data-points) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit too much of a nuisance for me to write a C driver for `gsl_multifit_linear` at the moment; as far as I can tell you must be running it from C or C++ as the `gsl` package for R doesn't appear to include a wrapper for this function ...

However, doing the linear algebra in both of the ways that you suggested (in R) gives the same answer as `lm()`:

```r
m1 <- lm(Job_Perf~Mech_Apt+Consc, data=dd)
y <- dd$Job_Perf
X <- model.matrix(~Mech_Apt+Consc, data=dd)
cbind(lm=coef(m1),
      solve1=c(solve(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X) %*% y),
      solve2=c(solve(crossprod(X), t(X)%*%y)))
##                      lm      solve1      solve2
## (Intercept) -4.10358123 -4.10358123 -4.10358123
## Mech_Apt     0.08640901  0.08640901  0.08640901
## Consc        0.08760164  0.08760164  0.08760164
```

The most common mistake I've seen when implementing regression by hand is to forget that R automatically includes an intercept column in the model matrix, but as you list an `alpha` estimate I guess you're not making that mistake ... ?

My best guess would be that you're setting up `X` incorrectly in some way: it should look like this

```
   (Intercept) Mech_Apt Consc
          1       40    25
          1       45    20
          1       38    30
...
```

---

Data:

```r
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Job_Perf Mech_Apt Consc
1   40  25
2   45  20
1   38  30
3   50  30
2   48  28
3   55  30
3   53  34
4   55  36
4   58  32
3   40  34
5   55  38
3   48  28
3   45  30
2   55  36
4   60  34
5   60  38
5   60  42
5   65  38
4   50  34  
3   58  38
")
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly my mistake, forgetting to augment the X matrix with column of 1's. Perhaps some people may find this (quite detailed) [http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/regma.htm](manual) interesting.